# How To Add new XElement Child when Parent Element is null

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML document with an Element that is null:

```
<Home>
    <Screen01 Code="BD"/>
</Home>
```

I want to add new child elements to the Screen01 element:

```
<Home>
    <Screen01 Code="BD">
        <Child1>N</Child1>
        <Child2>2</Child2>
    </Screen01>            
</Home>
```

The following code gives me an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Edit-I changed the code to use the way someone suggested.

```
 private void CreateAddRRNodes(string xmlAfterAttribsAdded)
 {
            XElement xDoc = XElement.Parse(xmlAfterAttribsAdded);
            xDoc.Element("Screen01").Add(new XElement("Child1", "N"));
            xDoc.Element("Screen01").Add(new XElement("Child2", "1"));
  }
```

How can I add new elements to Screen01 when it is null?

Comment: Your code more doesn't seem to match your example so it's not clear what it is you're doing wrong. My assumption would be there is no `Screen_H208` element.

Comment: I created a quick example using "Child1" to demonstrate the concept. The code is real. I have the "Screen01" element as shown at the top and I need to add those child nodes to it.

Comment: Then you should have `Screen01` in your code, not `Screen_H208`.

Comment: "How can I add new elements to Screen01 when it is null?" - you can't. Forget about adding anything for the moment - focus on why you're not finding the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ to XML and its XElement data type to the rescue.

> c#

```
void Main()
{
    XElement xml = XElement.Parse(@"<Home>
                                <Screen01 Code='BD'/>
                            </Home>");

    xml.Element("Screen01").Add(new XElement("Child1", "N"));
    xml.Element("Screen01").Add(new XElement("Child2", "2"));
}
```

Output XML:

```
<Home>
  <Screen01 Code="BD">
    <Child1>N</Child1>
    <Child2>2</Child2>
  </Screen01>
</Home>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried your code and I still get "Message = "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: I provided you working and tested c# code. It means your input XML is different. Please share your input XML and c# code verbatim.

Comment: Your answer worked. The problem was that my xml was more complicated than what I used in the example and the code could not find my element. I had to reference all of the parents. xDoc.Element("PL_Home").Element("Screen01").Add(new XElement("Child1", "N"));